# User sessions lost in Django

Tags: django

I'm running a site on Django that has been in operation for a few years.  We use sessions with a Redis cache backend.  After a reasonably minor update of Django to 1.11.16 from an earlier 1.11.* version, we're seeing that user sessions are being ended for no obvious reason.

One dependable way to get a session to end is to navigate to a url that causes a `history.replaceState()` to replace the URL.  As soon as that happens - the old sessions ends, the user is logged out, and a new session is started.

Any clues would help.

Comment: Did you see [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29203)?

Comment: Hadn't!  Looking into it...